# Confusion in applying Cauchy's Theorem of limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Cauchy's theorem of limits states that if $\ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=L ,$ then $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}=L   $$
If I apply this in the series $$S = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n}[e^{\frac{1}{n}} + e^{\frac{2}{n}} + e^{\frac{3}{n}} + e^{\frac{4}{n}} + e^{\frac{5}{n}} + e^{\frac{6}{n}} + ... + e^{\frac{n}{n}}]$$ 
Here $a_n=e^{n/n},$ Hence,  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=e \ $,  so $S=e$. 
I know this is incorrect because the integration gives the answer $e-1$. It seems to me that the reason for this is related to the terms of the sequence being dependent on $n$. I can't be sure of this because the same theorem gives the correct answer for the limit of this series(below) which is given in my book as a solved example of the above theorem $$ \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \right)=1  $$

Comment: The sequence you're calling $(a_n)$ is changing as a function of $n$. In effect you have a sequence of two variables, $a_{m,n} = e^{m/n}$ for $1 \leq m \leq n$.

Comment: @Bungo Then what's the difference between $(a_n)$ and the series given at the end.

Comment: The series given at the end is *not* a direct application of the theorem you state, on the face of it. Your book must be doing more.

Comment: If $a_n=e^{n/n}$ then $a_1+\cdots+a_n$ is $e^{1/1} + e^{2/2} + \cdots + e^{n/n}$, not $e^{1/n} + e^{2/n}+ \cdots + e^{n/n}$ as you wrote in your second displayed equation.

Comment: @MPW In my book the general term of the series is given as $a_k= \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}, k=1,2\cdots n$ and after that, without giving any explanation, $\lim a_n= \lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/n}}=1$, so using cauchy's theorem, limit of the series is also 1.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am indian. It's a book by indian author s.c malik :Mathematical Analysis

Comment: A correct argument for the second sequence would be that $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 + n}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}}$$ Since the left and right hand expressions converge to $1$ as $n\to \infty$, so must the middle. The argument given in the OP looks invalid to me.

Comment: @Bungo I know how to apply squeeze theorem, thanks anyway. Maybe the book is wrong, but why would the author use so many examples like this when the method is incorrect.

Comment: @Levi Bro have you got this concept clear ? Kind. of amuses me also as i find numerous examples done in the book using the same approach .

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh It's been some time. At that time I assumed that the author was wrong and this method given by him is wrong.

Comment: @Levi can you share your understanding with us ? I am in the same boat as you were and if you can help , that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply the theorem in the first case since $$a_n=e^{n\over n}=e$$which doesn't make sense. Another reason is that $a_k=e^{k\over n}$ that says $a_k$ is dependent to $n$ (!!) which is quite obviously  wrong . Instead $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{i\over n}=\int_{0}^{1}e^xdx=e-1$$also for the second one, I'm yet suspicious because of a same argument as the former one. In this case we can easily write that$$ {n\over \sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le{n\over \sqrt{n^2+1}}$$and use squeeze theorem to attain the result.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that  your series UP TO $n$ are $a_i=e^{\frac{i}{n}}$ but this defines the sequence only UP TO some $n$ which is fixed and thus taking this $n$ fixed tells you nothing about the later terms.